# Subtract two Pandas DataFrame time indexes from each other?

Tags: python, pandas, time, time-series

I have two DataFrames (say `A` and `B`), each with an index that is a `pandas.tseries.index.DateTimeIndex` class.

How do I find the number of days between each row of the DataFrames?

So that `A.index - B.index` would give me something like:

```
34
25
34
```

and so on.

Comment: IIUC then you need to call `to_pydatetime()` to achieve what you want e.g. `A.index.to_pydatetime() - B.index.to_pydatetime()` this will return a Series of timedeltas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both indices contain the same number of date observations, you can zip them and calculate the differences using a list comprehension.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), index=pd.date_range('2015-1-1', periods=5, freq='M'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), index=pd.date_range('2015-6-1', periods=5, freq='M'))

>>> [(d2.date() - d1.date()).days for d1, d2 in zip(df1.index, df2.index)]
Out[46]: [150, 153, 153, 153, 153]
```